# Hiding a list in an android application

Tags: android

I'm currently designing an application which stores a list of locations and displays them on a map. What is the best way to protect this list from being pilfered by another developer and put in a copy app?

I will be investing a lot of time in creating this list of locations through my own research and exploration so i'm hoping to keep it hidden.

Thank you

Comment: use sharedpreference of SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in your apps private directory.Android prevents other apps from assessing it.
However in a rooted device, the user can gain access to your private file.In this case you can go with some encryption.Obfuscating your app code with proguard is a good option as it makes reverse engineering your apk file difficult.

Comment: Ah i forgot proguard also works with android devices. Good idea. Is it possible or worthwhile to only obfuscate the location file or might as well do the entire apk?

Comment: It is possible to selectively obfuscate a source code, using the "keep" option of proguard.You can also have a look at DexGuard,(http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard), it is android specific.